# Xamarin.Forms - Disable SwitchCell OnPlatform Throws Exception for iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm tring to disable a `SwitchCell` in Xamarin.Forms for iOS in this way:

```
<SwitchCell x:Name="mySC" Text="Foo" OnChanged="myFnc"/>
<SwitchCell.IsEnabled>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Boolean">
            <OnPlatform.iOS>
                 false
             </OnPlatform.iOS>
            <OnPlatform.Android>
                 true
            </OnPlatform.Android>
        </OnPlatform>
</SwitchCell.IsEnabled>
```

When I run this code on an iOS simulator, an exception is thrown:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.NullReferenceException:
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   at Xamarin.Forms.Cell.OnIsEnabledPropertyChanged (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject bindable, System.Object oldvalue,
>   System.Object newvalue) [0x00000] in
>   C:\BuildAgent\work\aad494dc9bc9783\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Cells\Cell.cs:197

If i set the value to `true` for `OnPlatform.iOS` it works. if I don't use `OnPlatform` tag and set for example `IsEnabled="false"` for all platform it works well - the hypothesis is about a bug in iOS simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is that the `SwitchCell.IsEnabled` property has to be within the `SwitchCell` element. You are using the form:

```
<SwitchCell x:Name="mySC" Text="Foo" OnChanged="myFnc"/>
```

which closes the switch cell definition before you set the `IsEnabled` property. Instead try this:

```
<SwitchCell Text="{Binding .}" >
      <SwitchCell.IsEnabled>
           <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Boolean">
                <OnPlatform.iOS>
                     false
                </OnPlatform.iOS>
                <OnPlatform.Android>
                     true
                </OnPlatform.Android>
           </OnPlatform>
      </SwitchCell.IsEnabled>
 </SwitchCell>
```

so that the property is set within the definition of the `SwitchCell` rather than outside of it. I just tested and this worked on both iOS and Android, however using your code did fail on iOS.